# How can I get the contentWindow.location of the iframe, where the iframe src contains different domain name?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, location

How can I get the contentWindow.location of the iframe where the iframe `src` contain different domain name?
I have googled about this, but I found something like proxt, so how can I get the location of the window inside iframe where iframe `src` is not on the same domain?

Comment: I don't undestand the question. Fist you say, you try to get location of window with iframe, then you say you try get location of window inside iframe. Can you get exampla html code?

Answer (score 1):

Browser-side XSS rules prevent the access and display external URLs in contentWindow.location.  You can't do this.